# If statement to check if a variable is in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

So I have written the following program with methods: inputArray, selectionSort, binarySearch, and printArray. I am currently working on the main method and am struggling with what to do.

"Write the main method to invoke inputArray, selectionSort, and printArray methods. Next, your main method should ask the user to input a double value to use as a search key and then invoke the binarySearch method. Finally, the main method should print out the location of the key if it is in the list and an appropriate message if the key is not in the list."

How can I print the the index value from the binary search?

Comment: ask the precise problem you face.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava I am currently trying to do the following: "Finally, the main method should print out the location of the key if it is in the list and an appropriate message if the key is not in the list."

Comment: What does `binarySearch` return if the key is not found? Therein is the answer.

Comment: Hint: Try starting with `int found = binarySearch(array1, key);`

Comment: D E B U G. Answer lies there.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava, um... not really.

Comment: @Radiodef According to the code it should return -low -1. I thought about that, but I can't figure out how I should phrase the if statement to print out the needed text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the return value of the binary search method:

```
if (binarySearch(array1, key) < 0) {
    // key is not in the array
} else {
    // key is in the array
}
```

Comment: Wow. I definitely should've been able to think about that lol. My brain is getting fried.

Now I am stuck on printing out where the key variable lies in the array. I tried `System.out.print("The key is located at " + array1[key] + " in the array.");` but it didn't like that. I don't think array1[key] is legal. 

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @BronsonLane see cricket_007's comment to your question.